# Selenium find xpath of select node

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I am trying to generate the xpath for the following:

```
    <select data-bind="options: PrinterLabelTypes, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 
    'value', value: NewPrinterLabelTypeText, optionsCaption: GetText('SelectLabelType')">. 
     <option value="">Choose Printer Label Type...</option><option 
    value="Batch">Batch</option><option value="Despatch">Despatch</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried the following:

```
    //select[@data-bind='value: NewPrinterLabelTypeText']
```

But i am not getting anything back. Have i missed something. Is there a way to do it using the format above?

Comment: The xpath to what?

Comment: //select[contains(@data-bind,'value: NewPrinterLabelTypeText')] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `contains` when your locator is using part of the attribute value.

```
//select[contains(@data-bind,'value: NewPrinterLabelTypeText')]
```